# How to print a column name only time in left join if table have same column name

Tags: php, mysql

```sql
 SELECT A.status, B.status, C.status
 FROM A
 LEFT JOIN B ON A.id = B.a_id
 LEFT JOIN C ON A.id = c.a_id
```

Output of my query:

```
status status status
--------------------
1       1     NULL
0      NULL    1
1       0      NULL
0      NULL     0
```

I do not want null values.

I want output like this

```
 Id(A table primary key ) status
 --------------------------------
 1                           1
 2                           0
 3                           1    
 4                           0
```

Comment: put alias names to the columns

Comment: I'm not quite following what you mean, can you post a sample dataset?

Comment: i have three table A,B and c .In A table  i have two column id(primary key ) status.In B table i  have three  column id (primary key),status and a_id(A table primary key),In c table i  have three  column id (primary key),status and a_id(A table primary key). I run query  like above  i got     output like this status status status  three column but i want only id (A table) and status column

Comment: But `id` and `status` of which table

Comment: Edit your question accordingly

Comment: status status status

Comment: output of my querry
status status status
1       1     NULL
0      NULL    1
1       0      NULL
0      NULL     0
 i do not want  to null values
 I want output like this 
 Id(A table primary key ) status
 1                           1
 2                            0
 3                            1    
 4                             0

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.status as status FROM A left JOIN B ON A.id = B.a_id left JOIN c ON A.id = c.a_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
SELECT A.status 'A-Status', B.status 'B-Status',c.status 'C-Status'
 FROM A
 left JOIN B ON A.id = B.a_id
 left JOIN c ON A.id = c.a_id
```

Comment: output of my querry
status status status
1       1     NULL
0      NULL    1
1       0      NULL
0      NULL     0
 i do not want  to null values
 I want output like this 
 Id(A table primary key ) status
 1                           1
 2                            0
 3                            1    
 4                             0

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.status, 
    (CASE 
        WHEN ( A.status =1 ) THEN 
            B.status ELSE c.status 
        END 
    ) 
    AS ss 
    FROM A 
    LEFT JOIN B ON A.id = B.a_id 
    LEFT JOIN c ON A.id = c.a_id
```